# Fluid physics very low res when poured into an obstacle that moves

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, fluid-simulation

I am creating an animation of an obstacle filling with fluid, and the obstacle is moving. When the obstacle is still the animation looks something like real fluids. When the obstacle/vessel is moving the resolution turns to massive polygon chunks that poke through the obstacle. I've subdivided all of the meshes so they have a lot of vertices and I'm rendering at about 120 res, but the results are really ugly. How can I make my fluid behave realistically with a moving obstacle as the vessel?

Comment: That sounds really weird. The resolution shouldn't change over time. I tried to replicate the problem, but everything worked just fine and as expected. If you could upload your blend file it would be easier to check what is wrong.